# Continually display input dialog until user enters expected input - Android

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, dialog, xamarin.android

I'm trying to prompt the user for a Security PIN to allow them to access the app.  The part that I'm having trouble with is prompting the user with an input dialog repeatedly if the pin entered is not correct.

Not sure how to "re-display" the dialog if the pin is incorrect.

Current Code:

```
bool correct = false;
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.SetTitle("Enter Security PIN");
EditText input = new EditText(this);
dialog.SetView(input);
dialog.SetPositiveButton("Login", (sender, args) =>
{
    // check pin
    string pin = prefs.GetString("pin", "0");
    if (pin.CompareTo(input.Text) == 0)
    {
        correct = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // ??????? what to do here to redisplay dialog or prevent dismissal
    }
});

dialog.SetNegativeButton("Exit", (sender, args) =>
{
    this.Finish();
});
dialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your code into a function and call the function again in the `else`.

Comment: So recursively create dialogs until the correct PIN is given?

Comment: Simplest possible solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively on your EditText you could call method EditText.setError("Invalid pin.") and display incorrect pin that way instead of AlertDialog. If it errors do nothing till he sucessfully submits pin.

Comment: the problem I was having was preventing the dialog from automatically dismissing, which I believe will still happen with this solution.